# value in jquery.min.js selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and I have a question.

```
=ga.getText=function(a){var b,c="",d=0,f=a.nodeType;if(f){if(1===f||9===f||11===f){if("string"==typeof a.textContent)
return a.textContent;for(a=a.firstChild;a;a=a.nextSibling)c+=e(a)}else if(3===f||4===f)return a.nodeValue}
else while(b=a[d++])c+=e(b);return c},
d=*ga.selectors={cacheLength:50,*createPseudo:ia,match:X,attrHandle:{},find:{},relative:{">":{dir:"parentNode",first:!0}," ":{dir:"parentNode"},"+":{dir:"previousSibling",first:!0},"~":{dir:"previousSibling"}}
```

What does the **selectors = {cacheLength:** mean in jquery.min.js?
and also is it possible to change the value of cacheLength?

Comment: If you don't know what it means/does, why do you want to change it?

Comment: This is that line in non-minified format: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5d5ea015114092c157311c4948f7cc3d8c8e7f8a/src/selector.js#L471 It is directly editable without any magic. the source of that file should be enough to tell you what it does

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are working on developing the jQuery library itself, you should not be editing the jQuery file.

Comment: And even more so: you should not be editing the jquery *min* file.

Comment: You don't have to edit the jquery file to edit this property.